# add_image_size doesn't update current image sizes

Tags: wordpress, image, size

I'm using the `add_image_size();` along with `the_post_thumbnail();` from wordpress in my functions.php BUT I want the existing images to be refreshed automatically without having to remove and upload them again. How's that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are multiple plugins that allow you to regenerate your thumbnails without having to reupload them.
Some of them are:

https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/

https://wordpress.org/plugins/force-regenerate-thumbnails/

These plugins actually take the currently registered image sizes, and regenerate all of your images with these sizes, automatically. So once you make a change to your existing image sizes, or create a new image size, you should simply use one of these plugins to regenerate your images quickly.

Comment: Yeah I knew that. But I'm currently developing a wordpress theme which I'd like to sell on themeforest and I'd like to make it so it automatically regenerates the image thumbnails when the theme is switched into mine. Is there any way to do that? Thanks for the response, by the way!

Comment: You can write some custom code that will regenerate all images on theme activation, however i don't really recommend you do that - because there can be really a lot of images, and it would take a lot of time to do it. I'd recommend that you integrate a regenerate images plugin in your theme, and have an alert when the theme is activated.  The alert would notify the users that they must regenerate the images in order for them to appear properly.

Comment: FYI, for more information on how you can hook something on theme activation, you can read here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/6248/theme-activate-hook